# Images are not rendered with bookdown after updating packages

Tags: r, bookdown

I am using bookdown with RStudio to create a pdf-book. After updating latex-packages with `tinytex::tlmgr_update()`, images were suddenly not rendered anymore, either with `knitr::include_graphics()` or `\includegraphics{}`, but the figure caption is still being rendered.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Note that everything worked fine until I updated all latex packages (and tlmgr), so nothing has changed in any paths or code text. I have tried to uninstall `tinytex` and all packages, then reinstalling, but I still seem to have the same issue.

The `.tex` file created by bookdown have the following:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{images/test} \caption{\label{fig:test}Test figure}\label{fig:unnamed-chunk-1}
\end{figure}
```

Minimal working example:

````
--- 
title: "Test book"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_caption: yes
    citation_package: natbib
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
link-citations: yes
keep_md: true
keep_tex: true
---

# Test book

Test figure:

```{r, fig.cap="\\label{fig:test}Test figure", echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, out.width="90%"}
knitr::include_graphics("images/test.png")```
````

preamble:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

And these are my installed latex packages:

```
 [1] "amscls"           "amsfonts"         "amsmath"          "babel"            "bibtex"           "blindtext"        "booktabs"        
 [8] "caption"          "cm"               "colortbl"         "dehyph"           "dvipdfmx"         "dvips"            "ec"              
[15] "environ"          "epigraph"         "eso-pic"          "etex"             "etoolbox"         "euenc"            "fancyhdr"        
[22] "fancyvrb"         "float"            "fontspec"         "framed"           "geometry"         "glyphlist"        "graphics"        
[29] "graphics-cfg"     "graphics-def"     "gsftopk"          "helvetic"         "hyperref"         "hyphen-base"      "hyphenat"        
[36] "iftex"            "inconsolata"      "knuth-lib"        "kpathsea"         "l3backend"        "l3kernel"         "l3packages"      
[43] "latex"            "latex-base-dev"   "latex-bin"        "latex-fonts"      "latexconfig"      "latexmk"          "lm"              
[50] "lualibs"          "luaotfload"       "luatex"           "makecell"         "makeindex"        "mathspec"         "metafont"        
[57] "mfware"           "multirow"         "natbib"           "oberdiek"         "pdfpages"         "pdftex"           "plain"           
[64] "scheme-infraonly" "setspace"         "tabu"             "tetex"            "tex"              "tex-ini-files"    "texlive.infra"   
[71] "threeparttable"   "threeparttablex"  "times"            "tipa"             "titlesec"         "titling"          "tlgs"            
[78] "tlperl"           "tlpsv"            "tocbibind"        "tools"            "trimspaces"       "ulem"             "unicode-data"    
[85] "upquote"          "url"              "varwidth"         "wrapfig"          "xcolor"           "xetex"            "xetexconfig"     
[92] "xkeyval"          "xunicode"         "zapfding"
```

Comment: What is the latex version and the version of the graphicx package?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The newest version of Tex Live is always installed with tinytex, so I assume this is the April release this year. I'm currently using XeTeX Version 3.141-2.6-0.999. The graphicx package is not installed

Comment: Don't assume, look in the log-file or whatever. They have been some changes in the file name handling of \includegraphics etc, and the exact versions are important.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer modified the answer above

Comment: @UlrikeFischer more specifically it's XeTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)

Comment: That is neither the version of the latex format nor of the graphicx package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Where would I look to find this information? I am relatively new to latex so I am not entirely sure how to find it when using `tinytex`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I identified the graphicx package to be version 1.1. I am unsure about the latex version, if not the one stated above

Comment: the latex format is mentioned at the begin of the log-file. What is the version of the graphics package with s?

Comment: Have the exact same problem, running on `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.11.7)` and after inspection of my `./TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex` directory, it doesn't seem that I have `graphicx` installed at all (as seems to be the case for @Haakonkas)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: sorry, I read `graphicx` instead of `graphics`. The version of my `graphics` package is `2019/10/08 v1.3c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)`

Comment: no need to be sorry, I wrote graphicx, but I meant graphics ;-). Wait until tomorrow, then there should be a new graphics and latex version in the updates. Try if the problem persists with the new version.

Comment: There didn't seem to be a bug report yet, so I filed one: https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/161/